# How can I setup a dynamic gallery on a Layout page?

Tags: php, templates, yii

Here's the layout at the moment:

```
<header>
 <navigation>
 <section id="<?= $this->id; ?>">
     <?= $content; ?>
  </section>
<footer>
```

The page layout however (here called `main.php`), has the following hierarchy:

> [header]
>
> [dynamic gallery of images depending on db record id field] !!!
>
> [navigation]
>
> [content]
>
> [footer]

*Navigation* is equal on all pages, so they should be on the **layout**, correct?

The *dynamic gallery wrapper* is equal on all pages, so it should be on the **layout**, correct?

But the images themselves, they should be different depending on the database records.

I don't even know where to start here.

Can I have a little push please?

**UPDATE**

Should I create a method inside *components/controller.php* or mycontroller or whatever we may have, that retrieves the value from the model, and make that value available as a *public parameter* to be used on the *layout*?

Does this makes sense to you?

Comment: You can get a function in layout for these...

Comment: But that will force me to integrate the layout with a given model no? Making it, not agnostic... as, I believe, it should be... Care to detail your comment a little further please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly know, You must put your `non-changing` views into your main `layout`. But about views which will change during the request, You must create a different view for each one. Then, depend on your request you can `renderPartial()` your views.

Say, Your image view. 
First, We create a view with name `_image.php` in our layout directory (or any directory).
Second we fetch the data from database. for example we have images data like below:

```
$images=array('test1.jpg','test2.jpg',...);
```

Third, In each request you must send your data to your renderPartial method:

```
$this->renderPartial('//layout/_image.php',array('images'=>$images));
```

and in your `_image.php` you can manipulate your data, which is always different in different requests.

There are another ways to do this:

- Using the Yii's **DECORATOR** feature which is really cool. You can google it
- Using Yii's **CLIPS** feature

**UPDATE**

In this case, using Yii's `Decorator` worked for questioner.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with a possible approach, does that make sense to you? Be honest, I'm ok on learning new concepts. :)

Comment: ;) No, You must not create a function or ... Whenever you tell to your controller `$this->render`, Yii's go to looking for main.php layout and the view you addressed to your `render()` method.

Comment: Consider you have a profile controller. In your profile controller you have `actionView` action. in `actionView` action you put `$this->render('profileView',array('images'=>$images))`. Now in your `profileView` you have a `renderPartial()`. So tell this `$this->renderPartial('_image',array('images'=>$images))`

Comment: If you are interested to know more about Yii's layout and views, You can take a look at the Yii's official document which is really comprehensive.

Comment: I've read those. Still wasn't clear to me this specific case. Thanks for pointing out a solution. Decorators and clips, I believe, on this particular case, may not be what I'm looking for, because I'm not really asking for view changes, only dynamic content rendered I believe, so your approach seems to be appropriate.

Comment: Glad to hear that from you ;)

Comment: I still have a question, sorry. I'm not getting how should the layout main.php html structure stay on this case. If I call renderPartial to load the different images inside that gallery on each view, how can I load that between the header, and the navigation (both, part of the Layout and NOT on the views?). If I was not clear due to my bad english, I can rephrase.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47490/discussion-between-ali-masudianpour-and-mem)

Comment: After our chat conversation, we understood that a `decorator` should be used on this case. I will mark this question as useful, however, if it's ok for you, I will request your edition on your answer, so that, later, we may use it as a reference. Cheers.